# How to clear/reset all configured logging handlers in Python?

Tags: python, logging

**My Situation**
There may be one or more configured loggers, but I don't know what their names are.

**Requirement**
For testing purposes, I need to reconfigure logging handlers that were previously configured to log to stdout with a different format and logging level.

1. [caveat] I already know how to [clear one handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3630774/86263).
2. [caveat] I would prefer stdlib over 3rd-party libs (pypi, github, et al).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
print (logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.keys())
```

found by digging the sources of logging package

Comment: LOL.  I was totally going to answer my own question with the same thing.  Thanks.

Comment: I think that dict does not include root logger handlers

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I still haven't found a simpler way to do it than this.