# How to reset root logger config in Python

Tags: python

I originally used `logging.basicConfig(filename='logs/example.log')` to create a log file. After reading the docs I found that it is not recommended to modify the class attributes of logging. Now that I've changed these attributes how can I change them back/reset the logger module?

Output of the code below creates two log files, `app.log` and `example.log`. The latter is an artifact of `.basicConfig()` being called when I first tried to set up the logger.

UPDATE:

`grep -R "example.log" /lib/python3.8/` does not output anything so I'm not sure what was changed in the source code of logging to cause the `example.log` file to be created every time

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

LOG_FILENAME = 'logs/app.log'

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630774/logging-remove-inspect-modify-handlers-configured-by-fileconfig
# need to run this every time since I changed class attributes of logger
# still creates example.log file
print(logging.getLogger())
root_log = logging.getLogger()
for handler in root_log.handlers:
        root_log.removeHandler(handler)
# OR        
# logging.basicConfig(force=True) #one way to reset root logger format

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create console and file handler and set level to info
fh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILENAME, maxBytes=250000, backupCount=5)
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# ch = logging.StreamHandler()
# ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create formatter
ffh = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(name)-12s : %(levelname)-8s : %(message)s')
# fch = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s : %(levelname)-8s : %(message)s')

# add formatter handlers
fh.setFormatter(ffh)
# ch.setFormatter(fch)

# add handler to logger
logger.addHandler(fh)
# logger.addHandler(ch)

logger.info('instance logger')
# logging.shutdown()
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @wim I updated the question. Basically, I configured the logger using the official docs basic tutorial but only after I saw the note of how this shouldn't be done in practice. Now I am trying to figuring out how to revert the config and use the format and handler that I created for a `logging` instance