# Python logging messages get printed twice when importing package that use logging themselves

Tags: python, logging, open3d

When importing an external package such as open3d that uses Pythons logging functionality, my own logging gets printed twice.

See this example:

```py
import logging
import open3d as o3d

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def main():
    # set base level of logger on a module level
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 
    # create file handler which logs even debug messages
    fh = logging.FileHandler('log.log')
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # create console handler with a higher log level
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    # create formatter and add it to the handlers
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    # add the handlers to the logger
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.addHandler(ch)


    logger.info('This gets printed twice to console and once to log file.')


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Console output:

```
2022-03-29 15:06:20,533 - __main__ - INFO - This gets printed twice to console and once to log file.
INFO - 2022-03-29 15:06:20,533 - test - This gets printed twice to console and once to log file.
```

What would be the standard way to handle such a case where a logger exists in a external package? Is there a possibility to catch the logger from open3d and incorporate its messages into my own logger? Can I mute it altogether?
Thanks for the help!

**Solution that worked for me:**
With the hint from @Cargo23's answer and the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630774/logging-remove-inspect-modify-handlers-configured-by-fileconfig) question, I was able to inspect all the loggers and handlers and found a StreamHandler in the RootLogger.
With these lines just after the imports I was able to remove it:

```py
rootlogger = logging.getLogger() 
rootlogger.handlers.pop()
```

Although, I am not fully satisfied with this solution, as it does not seem very generic.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, yes you can.  Its always been a hassle when I've done this, but here are some guide posts:

The logging library has lists of the active loggers, formatters, and handlers that you can access.

Ultimately, you want to remove the handler that your library is adding.  I think that the handler can be attached to their logger and/or the root logger.

I think you can even just remove all the handlers and then add your own back in.

Hope it helps!

Comment: OK thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630774/logging-remove-inspect-modify-handlers-configured-by-fileconfig) post I was able to inspect all the loggers and handlers and found a StreamHandler in the RootLogger.
With these lines just after the imports I was able to remove it:

`rootlogger = logging.getLogger()`
`rootlogger.handlers.pop()`

All in all, this still feels a bit hacky though.

Comment: Agreed, I think that libraries are discouraged from adding their own handlers for this reason.  Can you upvote my answer if it was helpful?