Python logging: where are messages coming from
I have an application using lots of different packages and many of them are logging output. I would like to clean up my application's logs and perhaps disable some of the other packages' output. My problem is that I do not know where many of these log messages are coming from.
Can I configure / turn something on in Python's logging at a global level that lets me identify where the messages are coming from?

This question is similar to: Logging, remove, inspect, and modify handlers configured by fileConfig(). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Once you find where the messages come from, look into submitting requests or patches upstream to document what loggers are being used.

@roganjosh that's quite helpful, although not spot on. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55400327/865169 helped me identify how I can find the registered loggers in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.

@chepner https://stackoverflow.com/a/79102304/865169 shows me how I can reformat log messages to identify where they are coming from. That, together with https://stackoverflow.com/a/55400327/865169, lets me know which loggers to for example modify the logging level of selectively hide their messages.

You can try the following custom approach to identify where the logs are coming from
import logging

# Configure logging globally
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,  # adjust the log level as per your requirements
    format='%(asctime)s %(name)s %(module)s.%(funcName)s +%(lineno)s: %(levelname)-8s [%(process)d] %(message)s',
)

After this, you should be able to see some details about where the logs are coming from.

This is exactly what I was hoping for.
